# JavaScript nested for loop change tags

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I want to change that texts
why strong tags text not replace with small tags text.

```js
var small = $("small");
var strong = $("strong");
var x, i;
for (x = 0; x < small.length; x++) {
  for (i = 0; i < strong.length; i++) {
    strong.text(small.text());
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<small>small1</small>
<small>small2</small>
<strong>strong1</strong>
<strong>strong2</strong>
```

Comment: You're not using `x` or `i` in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be copying text between corresponding elements, you shouldn't use nested loops. Just use one loop, and use the index to access the other element.

```js
var small = $("small");
var strong = $("strong");
small.each(function(i) {
  strong.eq(i).text($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<small>small1</small>
<small>small2</small>
<strong>strong1</strong>
<strong>strong2</strong>
```

Comment: SyntaxError: missing `)` after argument list.